# Laravel - Caching Eloquent with Frequent Updates

Tags: php, caching, laravel, redis, eloquent

Is it possible to use caching on an object that will be frequently modified? For instance, let's say we have a BlogPost object, and there's a num_of_views column (amongst others) that frequently changes. Is it possible to update the num_of_views field, both in cache and in the DB, without destroying the cache object and recreating it? I can do it manually, however I worry about sync issues.

Comment: You don't need to destroy the cache object and recreate it, you can simply read and rewrite it

Comment: @MarkBaker But that really doesn't help anyone. In fact, decompressing, editing and re-compressing is usually harder on the server than just destroy and compress.

Comment: Clearly then, caching is not fit for any purpose, you've created a problem where none existed before. Caching is intended to provide performance improvements for relatively static data, not with highly volatile data. Typically you would be retrieving the cached data anyway to use it; in those rare cases where that use needs to changes the data, you would need to store it again..... I may be missing something fundamental here, but I still don't see any problem if you're using caching for the purpose it was created.

Comment: If what you want to do is manipulate counters, then you don't need to manipulate objects.... store the counters directly in cache and manipulate them there directly. Not all caching systems provide this option, but some (like Redis) do

Comment: I think it's better to change your model's schema. You can separate field's model into two models. One model that it's data is changing frequently (without caching mechanism) and another model that is not so (with caching mechanism).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. I don't know how you are doing cache, but you can replace a cache instance at any time:

```
public function updatePost($post_id, $num_of_views)
{
    if (Cache::has('POST.'.$post_id))
    {
        $post = Cache::get('POST.'.$post_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $post = Post::find($post_id);
    }

    $post->num_of_views = $num_of_views;

    $post->save();

    Cache::put('POST.'.$post_id, $post);
}
```

Comment: but still you are re-creating the cache. From many R&D I figured that any DB update will require a recreation of a Cache. As said, caching was basically used to speed up website for a static data.

Answer (score 4):

No, sadly there is not a good way to do it. But let me explain...

---

But there is actually a good reason for that - the whole reason of caching is to speed up the process of serving somewhat static data. For example, WikiPedia serves you 90% because it has so many users. WikiPedia articles rarely change, the popular one's that is, meaning caching is a great solution to keep some load off the servers.

In your case you would be wanting to modify a cache basically every request, you should never cache a view count by the way, and that would mean the caching functionality is rendered virtually useless. Even with a modification every 2, 3 or even 10 requests caching is still somewhat useless just because it's not the purpose of caching to regenerate every few requests but instead to keep load off the server.

Caching a request actually takes more resources than a regular live serving request would, so you can imagine that caching such variable data would not only be useless but also very problematic concerning your servers.

---

Another problem is that you propose to change only the num_of_views but keep the rest of object intact, but what you don't account for is that you can't actually do that with Cache. They way cache works is that it compresses whatever data you have into something else - it's a simple key 'post_object_x' and a value, which is usually some sort of encrypted string like base64 or others.

That means that the num_of_views field itself does not actually exist in the cache itself, unless you decrypt it and then modify it and encrypt it again, which is just as quick and resource intensive as destroying and recreating the object. So it's also just not possible from a purely technical standpoint.

---

I hope you could see why your idea doesn't quite work out and why it's also not the best idea in the world to cache any counters ever unless you have a massive site with billions of impressions - and even then you should only do it for very high request counts specifically and only short amounts of time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This was kind of what I was concerned about, however, as a follow up question:  Assuming we have a Product object ($product), that we had already retrieved from cache and has all the fields already populated, then how much of a cost is to update it with a new num_of_views value and save it? Aren't all these operations occurring only in memory (and therefore relatively inexpensive?)

Comment: It would cost the exact same as creating a completely new object and caching it again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it's very clear now for me

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. Separate the high-performance metrics from the database record and update the Php Model code to reflect that.  In effect, your "model", a model, that delegates its setters and getters to other the BlogSlowData and BlogFastData models (I forgot the name of this pattern).
2. You change the nature of how you write to your database.  So, for instance when you update a record, you pop it into a queue, which is processed quickly. I like using redis for this, the writes are queued into to redis and then another program reads the queue and writes it to the database and to the cache.
3. Finally, and probably the worst answer.  Is you can use Redis's LUA code to write to the updated metrics into database or if you are using mysql you can use the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html memcache libraries to integrate the data directly into your database.

You can also do a combination of 1 & 2, in which you increment the counters in redis, and push a record into a queue, indicating that BlogPost.id = 1234, needs $view incremented by 1.

-daniel