# PHP/Laravel: Maintain an object in memory

Tags: php, caching, persistence

Extending on this question: [Laravel - Caching Eloquent with Frequent Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936441/laravel-caching-eloquent-with-frequent-updates/26078513#26078513)

Assuming we have a Product object instantiated ($product) in a process servicing one user, can we not keep it alive in memory to be referenced for subsequent users? I'm not talking about caching, I'm talking about object persistence. Let's say I have 1000 requests per minute, and 600 require me to load the same products, it seems really counter intuitive to load these objects (either from DB or Cache), read from them, maybe manipulate a field or two, save, close, and then re-open for the next process.

I know (and I've used) APC can sort of help with this scenario, but it's still caching. From my understanding the object still has to be serialized and unserialized on each request. What in essence I'm asking is, can we have a background object thread or process that can be used to maintain a pool of objects that subsequent processes can reference?

Comment: PHP doesn't have any object persistence without caching, that's simply the PHP execution model - start/execute/terminate on every request - so the answer to your question is "No"

Comment: It's not my cup of tea, but PHP has an internal API for persisting objects in memory. I believe PhalconPHP takes advantage of this but I may be mistaken. See the docs on \Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory

Comment: @MarkBaker What about other web based (or languages utilized for web development) such as Python, Node.js, Ruby, etc?

Comment: By asking to compare PHP with Python/Node/Ruby/etc.... you're turning this into a language comparison question.... risking a flame war

Comment: The PHP execution model works perfectly well with caching mechanisms, and serialize/unserialize is very fast

Comment: And while you can't hold an object in cache, only a serialized object, APC (APCu in modern versions of PHP) is an in-memory cache using Apache shared memory, while other memory caches like memcached and redis were developed as language agnostic cache systems for use with a whole range of language such as Python/Ruby/etc; and you also have SQLite in memory databases

Comment: @MarkBaker this differs from what I've been told here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936441/laravel-caching-eloquent-with-frequent-updates/26078513#26078513

Comment: Does it differ? That answer explains that it isn't worth caching highly volatile data, but I can't see that it contradicts anything that I've said

Comment: @MarkBaker that answer indicates a high cost to caching, namely the serialization of values.

Comment: Serialization/Unserialization is a pretty minor overhead, a lot less than retrieval from a database, which is why caching is beneficial for data that is largely static in nature